# Is bulk update possible in JMeter JDBC requets

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

For one of the test plan, I have 1000's of records. It would be helpful to have bulk update. Has anyone implemented it or know of how to implement it in Jmeter. Also, can prepared update statement be used to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the given below steps to create a JDBC test plan.

1) Firstly, Download the JDBC Driver for SQL Server from Microsoft site.

2) Once the JDBC Driver is downloaded extract to find the .jar file of driver.

3) Now, open the Jmeter and create a test plan.

4) Select the test plan node and there is a section "Add directory or jar to classpath", browse the extracted JDBC Driver and select it.

5) Create a thread group and add config element "JDBC Connection Configuration" and configure according to your requirement.

6) Make sure to provide the variable name.

7) Now, Add a JDBC Request from the samplers in thread group section and use the same variable as you mentioned in the "JDBC Connection Configuration".

8) Select the query type as "Update Statement" from the drop down.

9) Mention your query in the editor panel.

10) Finally, add the listener to trace the output of your test plan and execute the test.

Hope this will entertain your question.

Comment: hi Zohair, appreciate you taking time out to address the question. I actually know how to setup JDBC connection in Jmeter. What I am not aware of is that how can we do bulk update or insert in Jmeter

Comment: For bulk update you can use csv data config and from csv file you can dump the data in your test plan for bulk update and insert.